# keep date time null values in the database as it is when I want to change other columns in that row.

Tags: c#, datetime

When I retrive a database result using linq,I saw that my date time is {01/Jan/0001 12:00:00 AM} when that column in database is null.And my problem is when I want to edit some other colums in that table then give me an error cannot insert the {01/Jan/0001 12:00:00 AM} value to the database.but I don't want to change that column.

can any one suggests me a method that how to keep null value as it is, when I don't want to change the that recode in the database.I know this is common scenario.

(and another not for me as a developer I not allow to change the database.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using `DateTime` type to map your database values, but `DateTime` is non-nullable value type. Use `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime`

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` is a value type object which mean that you cannot set it's value to `null`.

Use the `DBNull.Value` to assign the data.

---

[Value Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)